# What should i do to display on the objects at the index 0? i want to create a button to scroll how can display one element at a time?

Tags: reactjs

Currently when i use the map function it displays all the elements from the Array of Objects, what could be the possible ways to display only the element whose index is mentioned on the useState.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import joblist from "./JobsData"; 
const Jobs = () => {
    const [job,setJob] = useState(joblist);
    const [index,setIndex] = useState(0);

    return(
        <div>
            <h4> This is Jobs component</h4>

            {job.map((obj)=>(
                <h4 key={obj.id}>
                {obj.name}
                </h4>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Jobs
```

Comment: Just use the properties on `job[index]` instead of `.map`ing all the array elements? I'm not sure I understand where you're stuck.

Comment: gotcha, it was pretty dumb of me to not think that.